# C# Driver- LINQ - Aggragate - Contains in Int[]

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Mongo Driver Version: 2.2.4.26

I have the following query that performs some aggregations. If I remove the Contains predicate from my Where clause, the query executes successfully.

I would like to reduce and perform the aggregation on the server before realizing the data into the client memory. The issue I am encountering is when I use Contains in my Where clause, I get the following exception:

$project or $group does not support Sum({document}{ForecastQuantity}).

I would prefer to stay in linq implementation vs. the native if possible:

```
public class Forecast
{
    public int MarkdownGroupId { get; set; }
    public List<ForecastData> ForecastArray { get; set; }
...
}

public class ForecastData
{
    public int MarkdownNumber { get; set; }
    public double ForecastQuantity { get; set; }
...
}

public class Flat
{
    public int MarkdownGroupId { get; set; }
    public int MarkdownNumber { get; set; }
    public double SalesQuantity { get; set; }

...
}

public class FlatProjection
{
    public int MarkdownGroupId { get; set; }
    public int MarkdownNumber { get; set; }
    public double SalesQuantity { get; set; }

...
}

int[] groupIds = new int[]{ 1,2,3 };
var forecastProductDay = _mdb.GetCollection<Forecast>(collectionName);

        var forecastProductProjections = forecastProductDay
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => groupIds.Contains(x.MarkdownGroupId))
            .SelectMany(x => x.ForecastArray, (x, fa) => new Flat        
            {
                MarkdownGroupId = x.MarkdownGroupId,
                MarkdownNumber = fa.MarkdownNumber,
                ForecastQuantity = fa.ForecastQuantity,
                ...
            })
            .GroupBy(key => new {key.MarkdownGroupId, key.MarkdownNumber})
            .Select(g => new FlatProjection
            {
                MarkdownGroupId = g.Key.MarkdownGroupId,
                MarkdownNumber = g.Key.MarkdownNumber,
                SalesQuantity = g.Sum(y => y.ForecastQuantity),
                ...
            })
            .OrderBy(x => x.MarkdownGroupId)
            .ThenBy(x => x.MarkdownNumber)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This is probably an error in the driver. Does it work if you convert the expression to `Where(x => x.MarkdownGroupId==1 || x.MarkdownGroupId==2 || x.MarkdownGroupId==3)`?

Comment: Yes. That works
Converting to Where(x => x.MarkdownGroupId==1 || x.MarkdownGroupId==2 || x.MarkdownGroupId==3)

Comment: How many IDs do you have in the list? Perhaps you can create an OR list dynamically to work around this issue.

Comment: I am not certain the proper way to build the predicate to pass into the my Where clause. I attempted to use [link](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) , but I get exception: {"Unsupported filter: Invoke(x => (x.MarkdownGroupId == 1), {document})."}

Also tried using Any(), but with no luck:


        public static Expression<Func<ForecastProductDay, bool>> InList(int[] ints)
        {
            return x => ints.Any(i => i == x.MarkdownGroupId);
        }

Comment: How many items do you expect to have in the array?

Comment: I got it to work after I put .Compile() in expression.
.Where(predicate.Compile())

Answer (score 2):

Since the driver does not like Contains() or Any(). I had the build the expression dynamically using the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

List ints = new List() {1,2,3};

```
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Forecast>();
        foreach (var i in ints)
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(x => x.MarkdownGroupId == i);
        }
```

var forecastProductDay = _mdb.GetCollection(collectionName);

```
    var forecastProductProjections = forecastProductDay
        .AsQueryable()
        .Where(predicate.Compile())
        .SelectMany(x => x.ForecastArray, (x, fa) => new Flat        
        {
            MarkdownGroupId = x.MarkdownGroupId,
            MarkdownNumber = fa.MarkdownNumber,
            ForecastQuantity = fa.ForecastQuantity,
            ...
        })
        .GroupBy(key => new {key.MarkdownGroupId, key.MarkdownNumber})
        .Select(g => new FlatProjection
        {
            MarkdownGroupId = g.Key.MarkdownGroupId,
            MarkdownNumber = g.Key.MarkdownNumber,
            SalesQuantity = g.Sum(y => y.ForecastQuantity),
            ...
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.MarkdownGroupId)
        .ThenBy(x => x.MarkdownNumber)
        .ToList();
```